# Changing Price (Float) into Text

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am constructing an MS Access front end database for receipts.  One of the requirements when printing receipts is that the price must be also shown in text format, say $105.42 be shown as one hundred and five Dollars and 42 cents. Is this possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh joy, another stupid downvote for a question that has had a perfectly reasonable answer given. What is wrong with people?

Comment: Existance of a "perfectly reasonable answer" does not qualify a question. "What is the price of an egg in Barcelona?" has an answer, but would deserve a down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can certainly be done using VBA code. Microsoft has even been so kind as to post a Knowledge Base article, complete with source code, [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/95640).

Comment: As it is written, this answer is barely more than a comment.  You should incorporate the method from the KB article in case Microsoft decides to reformat their URL's and your link breaks

Comment: @psubsee2003 -- It is truly more a comment than a fully answer, but your suggestion is unreasonable.  The method is a complex packaged solution.  The opening request is extremely unusual, reducing the need for some kind of canonical and self-contained answer.

Comment: @Smanoli I understand the problems with doing so. The problem is this answer is not a good answer as it stands, so That is the only option to make it an acceptable SO answer

Comment: The post asks:  Is this possible?  The answer is: Yes.  The problem is with the question; the answer is complete.